# SQL - Count rows performance tuning

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have been going round in circles on this for sometime and am hoping someone can help me.

I have the following tables:

**Cases**

generic_case_id

case_subtype

**Case_Countries**

generic_case_id

country_code

**Papers**

generic_case_id

paper_name

**Archived_List**

paper_name

Now, I am trying to get a list of unique paper names which are not archived. Then for each paper list the number of cases associated with it.

```
SELECT paper_name, case_count
FROM (
     SELECT paper_name, count (1) case_count, row_number() over (order by paper_name DESC) rn, count(*) over() count_rec
     FROM (
          SELECT distinct(paper_name), generic_case_id
          FROM papers a, cases b, case_countries c
          WHERE 
             NOT EXISTS (select paper_name FROM archived_list d WHERE a.paper_name = d.paper_name)
             AND a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id
             AND b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
             AND c.country_code = '15618'
             AND b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
     ) GROUP BY paper_name
)
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 15;
```

This seems to work, although it takes a very long time to complete. Can anyone advise a cleaner method?

Thanks
Iain

Comment: Why the triple nesting? The external one can be surely removed.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements of the tables or use http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: Sorry - I am also paginating results and forgot to remove the outer row_number stuff. Will edit

Answer (score 3):

I think this is equivalent:

```
SELECT a.paper_name, COUNT(DISTINCT a.generic_case_id) AS case_count
FROM papers a  
  JOIN cases b ON a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id
  JOIN case_countries c ON b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM archived_list d WHERE a.paper_name = d.paper_name)
   AND c.country_code = '15618'
   AND b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
GROUP BY a.paper_name ;
```

If `papers (paper_name, generic_case_id)` is unique, then it's also equivalent with:

```
SELECT a.paper_name, COUNT(*) AS case_count
FROM papers a  
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM archived_list d WHERE a.paper_name = d.paper_name)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM case_countries c 
               WHERE b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id 
                 AND c.country_code = '15618'
              )
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cases b 
               WHERE a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id 
                 AND b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
              )
GROUP BY a.paper_name ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the structure and remove `count_rec` because you are not using it.  Here is a revised form of the query:

```
      SELECT paper_name, count(distinct generic_case_id) as case_count        
      FROM papers a join
           cases b
           on a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id join
           case_countries c
           on b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (select paper_name
                        FROM archived_list d
                        WHERE a.paper_name = d.paper_name
                       ) AND
            c.country_code = '15618'
            b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
      GROUP BY paper_name;
```

My guess is that the subquery takes time to execute.  Do you have an index on `archived_list(paper_name)`?  I also suspect the `count(distinct generic_case_id)` could be just `count(*)`, but this conforms to the logic of your original query (and the `distinct` is necessary if cases can be in multiple countries).  Also, if the `country_code` is really an integer, then you should remove the single quotes around the value.  In some circumstances, type disparities can affect whether an index is used.

That subquery could be expensive (a table name with `archive` in it suggests bigness).  In the `where` clause it is run for every row before the aggregation.  Moving it to the `having` clause might help:

```
      SELECT paper_name, count(distinct generic_case_id) as case_count        
      FROM papers a join
           cases b
           on a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id join
           case_countries c
           on b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
      WHERE c.country_code = '15618'
            b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
      GROUP BY paper_name
      HAVING NOT EXISTS (select paper_name
                         FROM archived_list d
                         WHERE a.paper_name = d.paper_name
                        )
```

Finally, switching this to an outer join might improve performance:

```
select pc.paper_name, pc.case_count
FROM (SELECT paper_name, count(distinct generic_case_id) as case_count        
      FROM papers a join
           cases b
           on a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id join
           case_countries c
           on b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
      WHERE c.country_code = '15618'
            b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
      GROUP BY paper_name
     ) pc left outer join
     archived_list al
     on pc.paper_name = al.paper_name
where al.paper_name is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT a.paper_name, COUNT(DISTINCT a.generic_case_id) AS case_count
FROM papers a  
  JOIN cases b ON a.generic_case_id = b.generic_case_id
  JOIN case_countries c ON b.generic_case_id = c.generic_case_id
  JOIN archived_list d ON a.paper_name = d.paper_name
WHERE d.paper_name is null
   AND c.country_code = '15618'
   AND b.case_subtype IN (50022,50023)
GROUP BY a.paper_name
```